# Will two AC devices in same socket share same low voltage in there DC circuits?

Tags: ac, mains

I have a 230v AC to 180v DC circuit with a MOSFET inline that I want to control via a PWM signal from a microcontroller (the load is a salvaged treadmill motor). To power the microcontrollers board I was thinking of using a usb wall charger and tying the negative reference of the two circuits.

Is it safe to assume that if two AC devices that are connected to the same house wiring circuit (they will share an enclosure) will have zero or negligable difference between there negative referances?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "negative refer(e)nces"? Typical house mains has two wires (plus earth), one may be hot and one neutral or both hot. Not sure about how it's done in Oz.

Comment: The negative of the dc circuit powered by the ac.

Answer (score 1):

The DC output of USB charger will be isolated from the mains, sufficiently to protect the user from shock hazard (assuming a good quality unit, properly tested and approved).

The treadmill controller is probably not isolated from the mains.

It may or may not be safe to connect the output of the USB charger to one side of the mains. Certainly the wires, connectors and insulation are not designed to be safe. The other isolation barriers inside the USB charger may or may not be. I would advise extreme caution on this, and you should **consult someone who is familiar with mains circuit safety and can look over your proposed setup**.

Keep in mind that if you tie one side of the 5V USB to the mains and then connect a micro into the 5V USB power and plug your computer into the USB port of, say, an Arduino you run good chance of blowing up the computer, Arduino etc. and/or giving someone a nasty (possibly lethal) shock. Everything connected to the mains is then not 5V with respect to earth, but mains voltage wrt earth.